# is there any way to leave margin in excel cells when aligning to one side or the other with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The thing is that I need to create a table and export it as a photo. There are some elements that I need them to be aligned to the right, but I want them to have some margin with respect to the end of the cell. What I did is to convert these numbers to a string, and then I added a blank space at the end (representing the margin)

```
coste_total = 1234567.89
cadena = "{:,.2f}".format(coste_total)
print(cadena)  # Salida: 1,234,567.89
```

After I do this, I put it in the excel file and add the margin:

```
ws.append((row[1]['Anyo'], row[1]['Mes'], coste_total + '  ' ,termino_energia + '  ', ter_pot+ '  ', exceso + '  ', resto + '  '))
```

However, when I do this, and I export the file, I get the corner marked by the control Green Error Checking Markers of Excel, because it detects that the values are numbers, and thus, the exported image has the markers too:

[image: Error marks]

My question is if there is any other way to leave a margin, or if there is a way to ignore these errors via openpyxl. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: You could leave the number as a number and use Horizontal Indent in Format Cells --> Alignment and set number to whatever suits. Or just center the number... That's Text Alignment "Working with styles" in [Openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html).